# No MIC input with HyperX AMP USB sound card

Tags: sound, microphone

last night i installed Ubuntu on my PC i've been messing around and after i installed some games and was about to play with some friends i noticed that i get no mic input from my headset

I'm using: "hyperX amp USB Sound card" and my headphones are "HyperX Cloud Stinger Core"

Is there any way to fix this?

Thanks,
- Daniel

Comment: Anyone guys this is really frustrating